# Testing difference in (dependent) slopes from a multiple regression?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression

Is there a formal test or an equation for comparing slopes from a multiple regression? That is, the estimates are not independent.

For example,

$$Y = β_0 + β_1X_1 + β_2X_2 + ε$$

Is there a formal test or equation for testing $β_1 - β_2$?

Comment: Do you mean $\beta_1 - \beta_2$?

Comment: yes, I meant B1 - B2

Comment: @NickMichalak I think you mis-edited it

Answer (score 2):

This linear model can be redefined to be
$$
Y = \beta_0 + (\beta_1 - \beta_2) \frac{X_1 - X_2}{2} + (\beta_1 + \beta_2) \frac{X_1 + X_2}{2} + \epsilon
$$
So, replacing your data $X_1$ and $X_2$ with $(X_1-X_2)/2$ and $(X_1+X_2)/2$, your linear model will be directly sensitive to $\beta_1-\beta_2$ and their sum $\beta_1 + \beta_2$.
One caution -- the result result will be highly dependent on the scales of $X_1$ and $X_2$.
For example, if $X_1$ is generally a thousand times greater than $X_2$, $\beta_1$ could be a thousand times smaller than $\beta_2$.
You'll likely want to "normalize" the two datas somehow to make sure that $\beta_1-\beta_2$ is meaningful -- making sure that $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same units, if they are dimensionful, or rescaling them to have unit variance.

Comment: Thank you @jwimberley! I have one more question then: If I ran this regression you defined above, would I be looking at the significance test for β1−β2?

Comment: The parameter corresponding to $(X_1-X_2)/2$ would be $\beta_1-\beta_2$, so its significance would the the two-sided significance test for the difference, yes.

Comment: Clever, I hadn't thought of this before, and I'm actually putting this into practice right now (+1)